# How to Iterate through an array with jQuery one by one with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of objects that I need to iterate through each object via button.  I have it setup and it's going through but it's skipping 2 on each click instead of going the very next record.  Below is what I have.  Can someone help me out please?  Or is there a better way to iterate through an array one by one?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 0;

  var values = [{
      "currentJob": "Job1",
      "StreetAddress": "xxx",
      "Place": "yyy"
    },
    {
      "currentJob": "Job2",
      "StreetAddress": "xxx2",
      "Place": "yyy2"
    },
    {
      "currentJob": "Job3",
      "StreetAddress": "xxx3",
      "Place": "yyy3"
    },
    {
      "currentJob": "Job4",
      "StreetAddress": "xxx34",
      "Place": "yyy4"
    },
    {
      "currentJob": "Job5",
      "StreetAddress": "xxx5",
      "Place": "yyy5"
    }
  ]

  i = (i) % values.length;

  //Here is where I iterate through using a button
  $(".btn-arrow-up").click(function() {
    i = i + 1;
    $(".current-job-box").html(values[i].currentJob);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type='button' class='btn-arrow-up'>up</button>
<hr/>
<div class='current-job-box'><em>result</em></div>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  I've converted your code to a snippet - it starts at index 1 because the `i++` needs to be after it gets the value - *but* it does *not* demonstrate your issue of skipping (2,4,6 etc) - it goes (2,3,4,etc).  You also need the `i=i%values.lengh` *inside* the click event to enable wrapping otherwise you get an error at the end. Please update the code to **demonstrate the problem**.

Comment: If it's skipping values, you might have run the code twice to get two event handlers - I suggest adding a debugger or simple `console.log("click")` inside the click event handler to see if it's running twice (note that latest Chrome puts duplicate console logs on the same line with (2) indicator, so may not be immediately obvious)

Comment: I was able to get it working great with the help of everyone here,  Freedomn-m your comment about Chrome made me think.  While it works in all browsers, I'm building this for someone on Sharepoint.  So when I port the same exact code over to Sharepoint, it starts the skipping there.  So Sharepoint is the culprit.  Any thoughts about that?

Comment: In order to get this working I had to add one line of code inside the button click function.  That line is 
`event.stopImmediatePropagation();`
This stopped it from firing twice.  It was bubbling up to the parent and making it execute twice.  Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
i = i +1;
$(".current-job-box").html(values[i].currentJob);
```

Try

```
$(".current-job-box").html(values[i].currentJob);    
i = i +1;
```

This result is because You first incrementing i which for start is 0 and after incremetation is 1 so next line takes second element istead of first element of array.

I also deleted this line:

```
  i = (i) % values.length;
```

Because i think it is not neccesary

PS: Hi and Welcome on StackOverflow :D

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome :-). Glad to be here.  I implemented your suggestions but unfortunately it still skips.  I added one more entry to the array.  When I click the button it goes like so.  Job2 then Job4 then Job 6.  Does that trigger any other thoughts?

Comment: The `i = (i) % values.length;` is needed *after* the `i=i+1` to wrap the values, otherwise you get an error at the end.  It's in the wrong place in OPs code but is not unnecessary.

Answer (score -2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
var i = 0;
var flag = true;

var values = [{
    "currentJob":"Job1",
    "StreetAddress": "xxx",
    "Place":"yyy"
},
{
    "currentJob":"Job2",
    "StreetAddress": "xxx2",
    "Place":"yyy2"
},
{
    "currentJob":"Job3",
    "StreetAddress": "xxx3",
    "Place":"yyy3"
},
{
    "currentJob":"Job4",
    "StreetAddress": "xxx34",
    "Place":"yyy4"
},
{
    "currentJob":"Job5",
    "StreetAddress": "xxx5",
    "Place":"yyy5"
}
]

i = (i) % values.length;

//Here is where I iterate through using a button
$(".btn-arrow-up").click(function() { 
if(flag)
{
$(".current-job-box").html(values[i].currentJob);
flag = false;
}
else
{
i = i +1;
$(".current-job-box").html(values[i].currentJob);
}
console.log(values[i].currentJob);

});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<span class="btn-arrow-up">ddddddd</span>
</div>
```

Comment: i hope you looking for this may be

Comment: Don't just throw a bunch of code at OP. Explain the problem of the original code and explain what you've changed to make it work as expected.

Comment: the problem when ever he try to click that button click first object array not appearing so i set the flag @Andreas

Comment: How is removing `debugger;` and adding a `console.log()` an explanation of the problem and your changes? o.O

Comment: Thanks Chandu for your response.  I'll give this a try!!

Comment: Please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Comment: TBH - this is complete overkill - there's no need for the "flag" - simply set `i=-1` or set `i++` after it's used.  Your code vastly complicates a minor issue.